# Compute analog signals as functions of two signals

Tags: adc, analog, dac, signal-processing

I would like to hear your opinion with respect to the following architecture for a supposedly easy task. I need to “compute” the value of two voltages depending on two signals.

Details:

I need to construct a circuit, that computes two voltages (U1, U2) depending on two analogue signals (S1, S2). Since the relationships U1 = f(S1, S2) und U2 = f(S1, S2) are nonlinear, I thought of using an EEPROM. To keep the system as simple and cheap as possible I thought of not using a uC or an FPGA.

So I thought about this scheme:
[image]

But I realized that ADCs, DACs and EEPROMs have mostly a serial interface, and the serial communication would complicate what I thought was a simple solution.
Does somebody have an idea, how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using ADCs and DACs with parallel interfaces instead?

Comment: What is the function you need to compute? What is the frequency content of the analog signals?

Comment: It's going to be simpler and cheaper with a microcontroller, unless the function is simple enough to do in pure analog.

Comment: The function I'm trying to compute is a second order polynomial in S_1 and S_2:
U_1 = a0 + a1 * S_1 + a2 * S_2 + a12 * S_1 * S_2 + a11 * S_1^2 + a22 * S_2^2 
U_2 = b0 + b1 * S_1 + b2 * S_2 + b12 * S_1 * S_2 + b11 * S_1^2 + b22 * S_2^2

Comment: S_1 and S_2 have arbitrary waveforms up to 10 kHz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I agree with @pjc50, you should use a microcontroller. They usually have built in ADCs. For example the Arduino uses a [ATMega328](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8161.pdf) which has a 6 channel 10-bit ADC built in with a full scale range of 5V. However, the Arduino ADC won't be able to keep up with 10 kHz at the default clock pre-scale factor of 128, so you'll need to increase the sampling rate of your ADC by lowering the pre-scale factor, as described [here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=6549.0).

After you get the digital codes, you can simply compute the voltages with your code. If you need to output actual U1 and U2 voltages, then you can use an external DAC like [one of these](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22272C.pdf).

For your enjoyment, here's [a tutorial on how to write code to operate an AVR ADC](http://maxembedded.com/2011/06/the-adc-of-the-avr/) and here is a [a study on the ATMega ADC clock rate vs. performance.](http://www.openmusiclabs.com/learning/digital/atmega-adc/)

Comment: thanks pikafu for your very complete answer. I was thinking of using PWM + RC filter to generate the analog signal to spare me the use of the ADC. I was wondering what do you think about using PWM instead of an ADC

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "generate analog signal"? The ADC doesn't generate the analog signal, just computes the second order polynomial, so you can't replace the ADC with a PWM + RC filter. However, you can generate a sine wave from a PWM signal if you use a PWM with a 50% duty cycle for a square wave output and filter out the harmonics with an RC bandpass filter. But you will have to tune your bandpass filter if you want to change the frequency of your analog signals. Is this what you were getting at?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I meant that I need to generate an analog voltage between 0 and 5 V, which will be feed to another circuit backstream to adjust its gain. Sorry, I made a typo, I meant of course "DAC", not "ADC". That is, I was thinking of using PWM output of the microcontroler + RC filter or instead using a "DAC" like an [LTC2755](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/2755f.pdf)